# Session expire on next request PHP

Tags: php, session

EDIT: PROBLEM WAS ON PROVIDER SIDE...

I am setting session value after submit form (action="same document") and echoing this value. If form is posted session is set corectly and echo value is OK. But after GET refresh (address on same document) value dissapear and session is no longer avalible...

Maybe trivial question but I'm desperate...

```
 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST["bigSubmitButton"])) {
   $_SESSION["user"]="nameUser";
 }

 if(isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
   echo $_SESSION["user"];
 }
```

My `phpinfo();`
[image]

Comment: It's likely an issue with something overwriting `$_SESSION["user"]`... you sure nothing else could be wiping the value, or assigning an empty value?

Comment: Could also simply be browser cache

Comment: Now I was change $_SESSION["user"] to $_SESSION["x"] and still nothing

Comment: Tried another browser - nothing...

Answer (score 0):

session_start() is supposed to return true if session is successfully started or resumed. Can you check its return value to test if session is working? Sometimes session fails and restarting server helps

Comment: Can you do echo 'a' before isset check cond and then echo 'b' after the cond.  Want to make sure u r on same page

Comment: Also make sure cookies are enabled on your browser.  Session is tracked by session cookie in browser. If cookies are disabled your session won't be tracked by your browser. Clear your cookies. Restart browser. Enable cookies. Try again

Comment: Create two files. File1.php and file2.php. In file1 set session.  In file2 echo that session. Both are for get requests. Let's see the results.

Comment: I received a reply from the Support - problem is on THEY SIDE :) Nice hour in hell :) can i close or delete all of this?

Comment: Your choice but it would be nice to keep so people who have similar problem can call support :)

Answer (score 0):

After `session_start()`, try to `var_dump( session_id() )`, if session id is changed, then, session is gone. I suspect you may use some framework, it has different way to process session.